# How to get and set Creation,Access and Modified time of a File In Epoch In Java?

Tags: java, linux, file, unix

I am trying to get the file attributes using Java Files library using readAttributes function of a file as I have to set them later on after performing task.But output of access and modified time from function returned map does not match access and modified time of stat command output.You can see the precision in java output is digits and stat command shows till 9 digits.

Map Output of File Attributes from Java java.nio.Files API readAttributes() function -

```
{owner=root, **lastAccessTime=2020-09-25T07:39:28.534538Z, 
lastModifiedTime=2020-09-25T07:39:28.534538Z**, gid=0, creationTime=2020-09-25T07:39:28.534538Z, isRegularFile=true, nlink=1, fileKey=(dev=35,ino=1574645), ino=1574645, mode=33188, 
uid=0, size=0, dev=53, isSymbolicLink=false, 
permissions=[OWNER_READ, OTHERS_READ, GROUP_READ, OWNER_WRITE], 
rdev=0, ctime=2020-09-25T07:39:28.534538Z, isOther=false, isDirectory=false, group=root}
```

Output of "stat filename.txt" command in linux commandline

```
$stat ef1.txt
File: ef1.txt
Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1048576 regular empty file
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
**Access: 2020-09-25 07:39:28.534538886 +0000
Modify: 2020-09-25 07:39:28.534538886 +0000**
Change: 2020-09-25 07:39:28.534538886 +0000
Birth: -
```

When we set the above attributes of Map again back to the file using setAttribute() from java.nio.Files API, the stat command shows

```
$ stat ef1.txt
File: ef1.txt
Size: 183             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 1048576 regular file
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
**Access: 2020-09-25 07:39:28.534538000 +0000
Modify: 2020-09-25 07:39:28.534538000 +0000**
Change: 2020-09-25 07:56:04.533689988 +0000
Birth: -
```

You can see that last 3 digits in access and modified time set to zeros.
Is there any way to set exactly same access and modified time shown in stat command to a file in java ?
Is there any way in java to get the access and modified time in epoch format and set it the same epoch time and achieve this ?

Comment: It appears this was fixed in Java 14.

Comment: I am using Java 8 right now. Any solution or workaround on this?

Comment: The only workaround I know of is using [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to run `stat -c %x` or `stat -c %y` to read the times, and `touch -a` or `touch -m` to set them.  Do you also need it to work in non-Linux systems?

Comment: Yes.I will have to add for windows in future. Also what command to use for reading and setting creation time ?

Comment: You can read the creation time with `stat -c %w`.  `touch` for Linux doesn’t seem to be capable of setting it.  As far as I know, the ext4 file system doesn’t store a file’s creation time;  `stat -c %w` will print a single hyphen (`-`) instead of a timestamp for ext4 files.

Comment: Windows may be a challenge.  `wmic.exe` will give you timestamps with microsecond resolution.  Getting the full 100-nanosecond resolution of NTFS apparently requires PowerShell (or a temporary VBS file or native code, bother of which I’d rather avoid).